# WPF DataGrid.items.Refresh() memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf

Good afternoon.
Help in solving the following problem.
If I set some **DataTable** for **DataGrid.ItemsSource**, which I will update in another thread, then periodically calling **DataGrid.Items.Refresh()** I will have a memory leak.
Is there a way to avoid this?

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
namespace TestDataGrid
{    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataWorker data = new DataWorker();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = data.dt.DefaultView;
            data.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;
            data.RunThread();
        }

        private void OnDataChanged(object obj, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
                //this.Title = data.dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

DataWorker.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestDataGrid
{
    internal class DataWorker
    {
        public event EventHandler DataChanged;
        public DataWorker()
        {
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.UInt64");
            column.ColumnName = "DATA";
            dt.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        private DataColumn column = new DataColumn();        

        public void RunThread()
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(DataChange);
            th.Start();
        }
        private void DataChange()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                dt.Clear();
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now.Ticks });
                DataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
                
        }

    }
}
```

If I change **DataGrid1.Items.Refresh()** to
**this.Title = data.dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()** for exemple, then memory OK.

[Start Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHZiJ.png)

[2 min later Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u14ru.png)

Project: [GitHub](https://github.com/DmitryMarugin/TestDataGrid.git)

Comment: That doesn't look like a memory-leak to me. That looks like normal (if aggressive) memory usage by .NET caused by its per-CPU-core GC heaps. How many CPU cores does your machine have?

Comment: I run on  i7-1165G7 with 4 core.

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use thread.sleep nowadays. Use await task.delay(n) instead. And invokeasync. I assume the real thing is doing something much more complicated.  Have you thought about an observablecollection of row viewmodels rather than a datatable?  Unless all your data completely changes every second then identifying changed properties and changing just them in the existing viewmodel is common. A fairly common requirement is to highlight changes with a different background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how

```cs
this.Title = data.dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

relates to

```cs
DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
```

This are two different operations targeting two different target objects.

The following simply assigns the cell value to the `Window.Title` property:

```cs
this.Title = data.dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

Whereas

```cs
DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
```

instructs the `DataView` to recreate the view. This means cached data is discarded, but still resides in the memory. It takes time until the garbage collector will collect this elegible objects.
This is not a memory leak.
There's some serious business going on under the hood of `CollectionView.Refresh`.
Just because it is a one liner doesn't mean you can compare its metrics to any random code line.

If the memory usage is an issue for you, consider to use a `ObservableCollection` instead of the `DataTable`.

If your depicted scenario is a real scenario, then using a `ObservableCollection` is more convenient than using a `DataTable` that has a single row and a single column. In your case, you would add the timestamp directly to the `ObservableCollection`.

Some suggestions to improve your code:

1. Don't use `Thread` and `Thread.Sleep`. Always use the modern `Task.Run` and `await Task.Delay` instead
2. Avoid `while(true)` constructs
3. Use a timer for periodic operations
4. Don't define public fields. Use properties instead. In your case the property should be read-only.
5. Prefer the delegate `EventHandler` over `EventHandler<EventArgs>`:

```cs
event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

over

```cs
event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
```

The improved implementation looks like this:

**DataWorker.cs**

```cs
internal class DataWorker
{
  private DispatcherTimer Timer { get; }
  public DataTable Dt { get; } = new DataTable();
  private DataColumn Column { get; } = new DataColumn();
  public event EventHandler DataChanged;

  public DataWorker()
  {
    this.Column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.UInt64");
    this.Column.ColumnName = "DATA";
    this.Dt.Columns.Add(this.Column);

    this.Timer = new DispatcherTimer(
      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
      DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
      OnTimerElapsed, 
      Application.Current.Dispatcher);
  }

  private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Dt.Clear();
    this.Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now.Ticks });
    this.DataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public MainWindow(TestViewModel dataContext)
{
  var data = new DataWorker();
  DataGrid.ItemsSource = data.dt.DefaultView;
  data.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;
}

private void OnDataChanged(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

### How to identify a memory leak

It is not enough to watch the total memory allocation. There are many reasons why the memory allocation increases over time. What characterizes a memory leak is that the momory contains objects that are never collected, because they are always reachable. The reasons for this a various. It can be because of static references or object lifetime management of event sources, data binding etc.

To identify the leak, you must inspect the objects on the heap. You do this by comparing snapshots of the memory. And by forcing garbage collection like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

If objects are still on the heap, although you expect them to be collected because you have removed all references, you *probably* have a leak.

Each good profiler allows you to expand the reference tree in order to identify the class that causes the object to be reachable. You the have inspect this class to find the cause for the strong reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers.  I know about Tasks.  I just gave an example of the most simple case.  Apparently I was confused by the work of the visual studio 2022 profiler, after 30 minutes of working in debug mode, the profiler shows more than 5GB of used memory.  But when the application is launched outside the debugger, there are no memory problems.

Comment: You should not profile an application in debug mode. Rather use a live profiler like DotMemory. there is a 30 days trial with full features. It allows you to profile the running application by hooking into the process. You can also manually force garbage collection to see how the heap memory behaves and what objects are reachable. See my updated answer to know how to force GC collection manually. You can execute it from a button click handler.

Comment: Furthermore to identify a memory leak you must inspect the objects on the heap and not the total memory allocation. You  want to see which objects are never collected.